# How can I calculate how many events are on a column for a calendar?

Tags: php, algorithm, math

I have x events with hour_start and hour_end. How can I find out which events intersect?

Answer (score 2):

Two events `a` and `b` overlap if:

- `a.hour_start` is between `b.hour_start` and `b.hour_end`

and/or

- `a.hour_end` is between `b.hour_start` and `b.hour_end`